# Every day is Thursday

Tags: riddle

> Sunday is Thursday
>   Monday is Thursday
>   Tuesday is Thursday
>   Wednesday is Thursday
>   Friday is Thursday
>   Saturday is Thursday
>   But...
>   Thursday is sometimes Saturday

Where am I?

Comment: This is the way my weeks work, when I get too distracted or overworked.

Comment: You are in high school

Comment: Did you write this riddle yourself?

Comment: I like how a puzzle about the days of the week has 7 votes. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Following on from @TTT (sorry, I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to your post)

> If every day is Thursday because you are on Jupiter, perhaps some days you can see Saturn and therefore it's "Saturday" which is named after Saturn.

Alternatively,

> If you were on one of Jupiter's moons, most days are Thursday because you're facing Jupiter but occasionally you face out to Saturn? Thursday/Saturday depends on what planet you see at the time?

Comment: [Here's a place](http://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/europas-jupiter-facing-hemisphere) that completes your alternative answer, where *all* day and night, every day and night, is Thursday thanks to [this phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking)

Answer (score 2):

You are

> on Jupiter.

Because

> Thursday is named after the [Roman god **Jupiter**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thursday). And so, obviously, every day is Thursday on Jupiter.

That being said,

> Unfortunately this doesn't explain why Thursday is sometimes Saturday...